# HTML Canvas effect - Image placing on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I need to have a effect like this website (https://www.addearstoyourpictures.com/home)

In these website when you upload your image (4000 * 400) , then you got a option to place a mickey mouse ear over your image and save it.

The mickey mouse ear is resizable from all four sides.

I need to imllement these kind of thing for one of my client .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am still searching... I know its a HTML canvas feature I am new to canvas thats why needs help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty good library for this is called [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/), it has all of the resizing and dragging things built in along with a ton of cool event handlers. I would try to stick to more specific questions next time, though, more code related.

Comment: Thank you @kalob .